# Laravel fortify echo/print/return the token when user register or send email password

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

Is there a way to know how laravel fortify generate the token when user sign up (by sending email verification with the token) and also when a user reset password (the token sent with the reset password link). I want to print/echo those for using it during unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I use Cypress to perform frontend testing and needed this too. In my case, I defined specific routes which cypress can access in order to retrieve the token. Inside the controller I do this:

```php
public function show (Request $request) {
        $broker = Password::broker(config('fortify.passwords'));

        $token = $broker->createToken($request->user());

        return response()->json($token);
    }
```

This simply returns the token.

I can than run a test like so:

```js
it('Should be possible to access the password reset page', () => {
    cy.createUserAndLogin().then(user => {
      cy.resetToken().then(token => {
        cy.logout()

        // Visit the password reset page:
        cy.visit('/reset-password/' + token + '?email=' + user.email)

        // Fill the form:
        cy.get('[name=password]').type('A completely new Password 1')
        cy.get('[name=password_confirmation]').type('A completely new Password 1')
        cy.get('button.primary').click()

        // I should now be able to login:
        cy.visit('/login')
        cy.get('[name=email]').type(user.email)
        cy.get('[name=password]').type('A completely new Password 1')
        cy.get('#loginform').submit()

        cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/spa')
      })
    })
  })
```

`cy.resetToken().then(token => {})` makes the actual call to the server using a cypress support command and returns the token.

Off course, the trick is in the `cy.visit('/reset-password/' + token + '?email=' + user.email)` line. You can do something similar in your frontend testing system.